# Counting Frequencies

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of frequencies the word tags I-GENE and O appeared in a file.

The example of the file I'm trying to compute is this:

```
45 WORDTAG O cortex 
2 WORDTAG I-GENE cdc33 
4 WORDTAG O PPRE 
4 WORDTAG O How
44 WORDTAG O if
```

I am trying to compute the sum of word[0] (column 1) in the same category (ex. I-GENE) same with category (ex. O)

In this example:

The sum of words with category of I-GENE is 2
and the sum of words with category of O is 97

MY CODE:

```
import os

def reading_files (path):

    counter = 0

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

        for file in files:
            if file != ".DS_Store":
                if file == "gene.counts":
                    open_file = open(root+file, 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
                    for line in open_file:
                        tmp = line.split(' ')

                        for words in tmp:

                            for word in words:
                                if (words[2]=='I-GENE'):
                                   sum = sum + int(words[0]
                                if (words[2] == 'O'):
                                   sum = sum + int(words[0])

                            else:
                                print('Nothing')

                        print(sum)
```

Comment: So... what does your code do? What do you want it to do instead? Please provide inputs and expected and actual outputs.

Comment: In programming that's not called frequencies which is a periodic word, number of occurrences within a period. Ín programming the word is OCCURENCES and wordcount and you will have alot more luck seaching that keyword, in fact you type it on goog wiht string and python you will have answer almost straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the word loop - you don't use it

```
for word in words:
```

I would use a dictionary for this - if you want solve this generally.
While you read the file, fill a dictionary with:
 - if you have the key in the dict already -> Increase the value for it
 - If it is a new key, then add to the dict, and set value to it's value.

```
def reading_files (path):
freqDict = dict()
...
for words in tmp:
    if words[2] not in freqDict():
        freqDict[words[2]] = 0
    freqDict[words[2]] += int(words[0])
```

After you created the dictionary, you can return it and use it with keyword, or you can pass a keyword for the function, and return the value or just print it.
I prefer the first one - Use as less file IO operation as possible. You can use the collected data from memory.

For this solution I wrote a wrapper:

```
def getValue(fDict, key):
if key not in fDict:
    return "Nothing"
return str(fDict[key])
```

So it will behave like your example.

It is not neccessary, but a good practice: close the file when you are not using it anymore.